# How to draw buttons cuted by circle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to do the following widget on Flutter:

[image]

As you can see, it's pretty hard. One idea would be to use .png for the buttons cutted by the circle, but I don't think this would look good on high resolutions.

My idea, currently, is to use a `Stack` so I can place the buttons where they neeed to be. Then I can put a blank circle on the center to erase the buttons. However this is still not good, because then the widget could only be placed on places with blank background.

Should I stick with the `Stack` approach?

I started with something like this:

```
    Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 0.5,
                          heightFactor: 0.5,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            ),
                          )),
                      FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 0.5,
                          heightFactor: 0.5,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            ),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 0.5,
                          heightFactor: 0.5,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            ),
                          )),
                      FractionallySizedBox(
                          widthFactor: 0.5,
                          heightFactor: 0.5,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            ),
                          ))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ]))
```

but I get

```
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height.
```

I don't know why since I placed things inside a `Container` with fixed size (which is also undesired).

**UPDATE:**

I tried the answer below, but it requires a colored circle.

Is it possible to draw this by some other method?

[image]

Comment: If you have the shape formula, you can implement your CustomPainter (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html). It can draw any shape. If you think it is too much work, you also can use a Transparent image instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bad idea to use the Stack widget in this case, just remember to give it a height to prevent some problems inside columns. Here's an example of how you can create it:

```
//A model of the button to save some lines of code
Widget button(
    {VoidCallback onPressed, double buttonWidth, String buttonText}) {
  return Container(
    width: buttonWidth,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    height: 80,
    child: RaisedButton(
      color: Colors.purpleAccent[200],
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text(buttonText),
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double buttonWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5; //getting half of the current width for each button

  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 160,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [

                  //two rows, each one with 2 buttons

                  Row(
                    children: [
                      button(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        buttonWidth: buttonWidth,
                        buttonText: 'button1',
                      ),
                      button(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        buttonWidth: buttonWidth,
                        buttonText: 'button2',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      button(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        buttonWidth: buttonWidth,
                        buttonText: 'button3',
                      ),
                      button(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        buttonWidth: buttonWidth,
                        buttonText: 'button4',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(    //a container to give a white space around the inner widget
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Align(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red,       //the main button
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Result:

[image: button]

Comment: I tied and it kinda works, but the circle is white. What if I have a background with other color? I cannot know the color of the background inside the widget. Can you look at my update?

Comment: you can use the same color of the background like this:

Theme.of(context).canvasColor

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a custom clipper, that will show anything at the background, it will be like this:

[image] 
 
Here you are the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        canvasColor: Colors.yellow,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      button(index: 0),
                      button(index: 1),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      button(index: 2),
                      button(index: 3),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Center(
                child: Align(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red, //the main button
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget button(
    {VoidCallback onPressed,
    double buttonWidth,
    String buttonText,
    int index}) {
  return Center(
    child: ClipPath(
      clipper: MyCustomClipper(index: index),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.pink,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          width: 150,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  int index = 0;

  MyCustomClipper({this.index});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var controlPoint = Offset(50, 50);
    var endPoint = Offset(size.width - 58, size.height);

    var endPoint1 = Offset(0, 53);

    var endPoint2 = Offset(size.width, 58);

    var endPoint3 = Offset(58, 0);

    List listOfPaths = [
      Path()
        ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
        ..lineTo(size.width, 53)
        // ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2 + 20, 58, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy)
        ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..close(),
      Path()
        ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
        ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        ..lineTo(58, size.height)
        // ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..quadraticBezierTo(
            controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, endPoint1.dx, endPoint1.dy)
        ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..lineTo(0, 58)
        ..close(),
      Path()
        ..lineTo(size.width - 58, 0)
        // ..lineTo(size.width, size.wid/2)
        // ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2 + 20, 52, endPoint2.dx, endPoint2.dy)
        ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..close(),
      Path()
        ..moveTo(size.width, 0)
        ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        ..lineTo(0, size.height)
        ..lineTo(0, 58)
        ..quadraticBezierTo(
            controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, endPoint3.dx, endPoint3.dy)
        // ..lineTo(0, 0)
        ..close(),
    ];

    return listOfPaths[index];
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer given by @LOfG is already wonderful and addresses your UI requirements very well, but if you still need a variation of it then here is the example of it with the purple color scheme and inner shadow as you updated in the question.

It also implements the `onTap` event so you can easily bind the function of your choice with ease.

Final Output:

[image]

**Full Example Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DpadButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DpadButtonsState createState() => _DpadButtonsState();
}

class _DpadButtonsState extends State<DpadButtons> {
  String button = "";

  void _selectedButton(String selectedButton) {
    setState(() {
      button = selectedButton;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double heightMain = 100;
    double widthMain = 180;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dpad Button")),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                buildButtonRow(
                  b1: "Button 1",
                  b2: "Button 2",
                  onClick: _selectedButton,
                  width: widthMain,
                  height: heightMain,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                buildButtonRow(
                  b1: "Button 3",
                  b2: "Button 4",
                  onClick: _selectedButton,
                  width: widthMain,
                  height: heightMain,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: heightMain * 1.5,
                height: heightMain * 1.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 100,
              top: 200,
              child: Text(
                "You clicked : $button",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Row buildButtonRow(
      {String b1, String b2, Function onClick, double width, double height}) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            onClick(b1);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple[900],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.2),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.80,
              height: height * 0.80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.purple[200],
                    spreadRadius: -8,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(b1)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            onClick(b2);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple[900],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.2),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.80,
              height: height * 0.80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.purple[200],
                    spreadRadius: -8,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(b2)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to create a button of the following shape:

[image]

Then I have answered about it here: [How to apply glass-like 3D effect on a RoundedRectangleBorder button on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178180/5669120)

[image]