# How to apply glass-like 3D effect on a RoundedRectangleBorder button on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a button with these effects:

[image]

Currently I have a rounded flat button like this:

```
RaisedButton(
    color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
```

How can I apply such effects to make it look 3D? I don't know the name of this effect but it looks like glass

Comment: You can provide `shadow` to it so that it would look like an elevated container.

Comment: @HardikKumar there's no `shadow` property on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

Comment: Yeah, I know that, you can use `Container` instead which has a `decoration` property. You can decorate `Container` as you want.

Comment: Can you send a shown example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 7):

**Final Output:**

[image]

We can achieve this look using `ClipPath` and `CustomClipper`,

It will be a little hard to comprehend the code below at first if you are not accustomed to using `CustomClipper` so you might have to spend some time understanding how `path.lineTo` and `path.quadraticBezierTo` are implemented.

Once you get a hang of it, you will be able to replicate this button as well as even more complex shapes with ease.

**Full Source Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: RoundedButton(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class RoundedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  RoundedButton({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _RoundedButtonState createState() => _RoundedButtonState();
}

class _RoundedButtonState extends State<RoundedButton> {
  int counter = 0;

  void _counter() {
    setState(() {
      counter = counter + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: CustomClipperButton(),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: _counter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 150,
                      color: Colors.purple[900],
                      child: Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.purple[300],
                              spreadRadius: 0,
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: -70,
                    right: -90,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 180,
                      height: 180,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.purple[800],
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Text(
            "You Pressed $counter times",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClipperButton extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.2);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.8);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height, size.width * 0.1, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.7 - 10, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.7, size.height, size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.95);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.30,
        size.width - 10, size.height * 0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height * 0.3, size.width, size.height * 0.3 - 10);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width * 0.9, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.1, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, size.height * 0.2);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**List To Documentations:**

1. [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)
2. [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)
3. [lineTo()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/lineTo.html)
4. [quadraticBezierTo()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html)

PS: I have used a dimension of 300*150 for the button container, you might have to take into account the dimension of the button that you will be creating, so calculating x,y coordinates will be a bit cumbersome at times, but as I said in the beginning after you understand the `lineTo()` and `quadraticBezierTo()` then implementation button of any size and shape will be very easy.

**Update:**

New Example without using `ClipPath` and probably the easiest:

Final Output:

[image]

The only thing here you have to sacrifice is the tiny rounded edges where that central quarter-circle starts-ends.

Width and heights can be dynamically set globally if required.

If You ask me, I will suggest you follow this method instead of `ClipPath`, which looks uniform, less complex, and easy to configure.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DpadButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DpadButtonsState createState() => _DpadButtonsState();
}

class _DpadButtonsState extends State<DpadButtons> {
  String button = "";

  void _selectedButton(String selectedButton) {
    setState(() {
      button = selectedButton;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double heightMain = 100;
    double widthMain = 180;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Dpad Button")),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                buildButtonRow(
                  b1: "Button 1",
                  b2: "Button 2",
                  onClick: _selectedButton,
                  width: widthMain,
                  height: heightMain,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                buildButtonRow(
                  b1: "Button 3",
                  b2: "Button 4",
                  onClick: _selectedButton,
                  width: widthMain,
                  height: heightMain,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: heightMain * 1.5,
                height: heightMain * 1.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 100,
              top: 200,
              child: Text(
                "You clicked : $button",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Row buildButtonRow(
      {String b1, String b2, Function onClick, double width, double height}) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            onClick(b1);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple[900],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.2),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.80,
              height: height * 0.80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.purple[200],
                    spreadRadius: -8,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(b1)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            onClick(b2);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple[900],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.2),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.80,
              height: height * 0.80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.purple[200],
                    spreadRadius: -8,
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(b2)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this loks very promising. However, when putting everything together, I noted that the bezier curve that forms the part that the circle cuts, is not a circle (its a bezier curve). Is there a way to substitute that bezier by a path that is a quarter of a circle?

Comment: You can make bezier curve to absulute circles. Just have to declare control points properly.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested but the widget that you done is very fixed for this specific width and height. I tried making it dependent on arbitrary width and height but respecting proportions, this is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/459pQYB. Apparently the inner shadows that you added wont work in proportion (code: https://pastebin.com/GzCnFgaR). Would you kindly update for a variable width/height? I promise to give you another bounty on top of this one.

Comment: wait, will look into it.

Comment: one easy workaround, create an SVG in any image editor and convert it into the path from here: https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter/#:~:text=Convert%20your%20SVG%20file%20directly,hit%20the%20respective%20buttons%20underneath.

Comment: I think this fixes the problem of the quadratic bezier being a circle. I have the SVG model so it won't be a problem. However, it does not solve the shadow problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225661/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-guerlando-ocs).

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to use image as button resource.
If you want the 3D shadow effect by code, it can be achieved by `shadows` inside `Container` widget.

### First: build the shape of the button

Here is the shape path

```
Path myCustomShapePath(Rect rect) {
  var r1 = rect.height * 0.5;
  var r2 = rect.height * 0.35;
  var r3 = rect.height * 0.1;
  var L = rect.left;
  var R = rect.right;
  var T = rect.top;
  var B = rect.bottom;

  return Path()
    ..moveTo(L, T + r2)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(L, T, r2, r2), pi, 0.5 * pi, false)
    ..lineTo(R - r2, T)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(R - r2, T, r2, r2), 1.5 * pi, 0.5 * pi, false)
    ..lineTo(R, B - r1 - 2 * r3)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(R - r3, B - r1 - 2 * r3, r3, r3), 0, 0.5 * pi, false)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(R - r1 - r3, B - r1 - r3, r1 * 2.5, r1 * 2.5),
        1.5 * pi, -0.5 * pi, false)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(R - r1 - 2 * r3, B - r3, r3, r3), 0, 0.5 * pi, false)
    ..lineTo(R - r2, B)
    ..arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(L, B - r2, r2, r2), 0.5 * pi, 0.5 * pi, false)
    ..close();
}
```

Because I want the custom shape for the button and avoid the shadow blur outside of the button, so I extend both `ShapeBorder` and `CustomClipper<Path>` with the same path:

**CustomClipPath**

```
class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) =>
      myCustomShapePath(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

**CustomShape**

```
class CustomShape extends ShapeBorder {
  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => const EdgeInsets.only();

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) =>
      getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) =>
      myCustomShapePath(rect);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => null;
}
```

### Second: use BoxShadow to draw the button

Use `ClipPath` to clip the shadow blur and use `shadows` inside Container's `ShapeDecoration` to draw the 3D effect:

```
class MySolidButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: CustomClipPath(),
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: CustomShape(),
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.white),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFF550091),
              offset: Offset(0, 20),
              blurRadius: 5,
              spreadRadius: 10,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFFA93EF0),
              blurRadius: 10,
              spreadRadius: -2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Result

[image]

---

**Update**:

| BoxShadow 1 | BoxShadow 2 | BoxShadow 3 | Combine (Before Clip) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| color: Colors.white | color: Color(0xFF550091) blurRadius: 5 spreadRadius: 10 | color: Color(0xFFA93EF0) blurRadius: 10 spreadRadius: -2 | (shadow 2 move down) offset: Offset(0, 20) |
| [image: shadow 1] | [image: shadow 2] | [image: shadow 3] | [image] |

**LayoutBuilder**

```
  child: Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        // get constraint here 300 x 200
        return Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            shape: CustomShape(),
```

Comment: This looks amazing!

Comment: This is very impressive!!!!! The one thing that wasn't quite right for me was the shadows when I make the button bigger. Do you know how to make the shadows also follow the width and height? Some proportional constant or something?

Comment: The shadow effect is combine with 3 colors of `BoxShadow`. The shadow default is **same shape as container**. `spreadRadius` represent the shadow size(which mean negative shrink the shadow). `blurRadius` represent the blur effect. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html)
You can try these values to get your result.

Comment: By the way the shape formula is by my assumption, it may cause the shape break when `height > width`.

Comment: "You can try these values to get your result", which values?

Comment: I update with how the shadows combine. Because the values all need to set in pixel, you can wrap the LayoutBuilder which can get parent size and multiple it with a factor: [How can I layout widgets based on the size of the parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558368/how-can-i-layout-widgets-based-on-the-size-of-the-parent)

Comment: @yellowgray I missed the bounty award so it auto awarded but I opened another one to award your extremely detailed and great answer. I have to wait 24hrs to award you, so just wait. Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: (this is a friend's account)